# Node mapping with edge weights

Tags: graph-theory

For an academic paper, I wish to use node mapping and weighted edge. I do not understand the concepts quiet clearly. I have a weight on each edge.

The graph for which am trying to solve the problem is a bipartite graph. As we know, there are set of nodes in left side and set of nodes in the right side. The total nodes in left side will always be lesser than the total nodes in right side. For each node in left side, I am trying to find a match in the right side. All the edges have a weight on them. So to solve the mapping problem, I am planning to use the maximum edge weight of each node.  However, what if two nodes have the same edge weight? Which one would I choose? Also, am I correct in understanding the node mapping concept in graph theory?

Comment: As far as I (and google) know, "node mapping" is not well-known terminology in graph theory, so it's unclear what you are trying to do. Is a vertex on the right side allowed to be "matched" to more than one vertex on the left?